# Scopes to query group mailbox via Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

are there specific Scopes to query group mailboxes with Microsoft graph?
Or should mailbox.read be enough?

My customer is developing an app which shall be able to read this group mailbox and we have to grant the needed permissions.

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "group mailbox".

If you mean messages within an O365/Outlook Group, then you'll need [`Group.Read.All`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#group-permissions). Also, these are not [`messages`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message), they are [`conversations`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/conversation) so you'll need to use a different set of APIs to work with them.

If you mean a shared mailbox within Exchange, then you'll need [`Mail.Read.Shared`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#mail-permissions) in order to access a shared mailbox.